# Netbeans 8 - Mac OS X JVM for project still executing after killing project execution

Tags: java, macos, netbeans, netbeans-8

I'm running Netbeans 8.0 on Mac OS X Mavericks.

I have a very simple project to verify an issue I'm seeing with executing project and killing them and seeing the JVM instance still executing after I kill the project process within Netbeans.

`public class Tester {
    private static final Logger logger=Logger.getLogger(Tester.class);
    public static void main ( String[] args ){
        for( int x=0;x<34324324;x++){
            logger.info("hey");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Tester.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}`

After I execute this from within Netbeans and I kill the project execution from within Netbeans, and I do a processs list on the terminal, the JVM process tied to this project process is still executing.  I even tail my log4j log file and it's still writing to the logger.

Even after totally killing Netbeans - the JVM process is still running.

I have noticed this bug report:
https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=232322

However this bug report is specifically in the context of Multithreaded applications, which mine clearly is not.

Comment: Multitasking versus multithreading is applied to your case.

Comment: So are you saying the bug report most likely still applies to my issue?